# How to set the color of an horizontal bar chart?

Tags: pgfplots, color, bar-chart, pattern

I am trying to make a violet horizontal bar chart. So far I managed to make a violet outline with a blue filling, but when I try to get a violet filling Latex compilation fails.

Here is an example of what I'd want:

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}

    \usepackage{color} %include colors
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
          [
          axis lines*=left,
          xbar,
          xlabel={Pourcentage d'activité},
          symbolic y coords={Énergies},
          ytick=data,
          xmin=0,
          xmax=50,
          nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
          nodes near coords align={horizontal}
          ]
          \addplot[draw=violet, pattern=horizontal lines light violet]
          coordinates{(33,Énergies)};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

However if I compile with:

```
$ latexmk -pdf -pdflatex=lualatex -outdir=tmp test.tex
```

I get the following error:

```
! Package pgf Error: Undefined pattern `horizontal lines light violet'.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.25     \end{axis}
```

While the error message seems clear, if I only change `horizontal lines light violet` for `horizontal lines light blue`, the code compiles and I get the following output:

[Blue bars with a violet outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVcR1.jpg)

Moreover, if I look at the manual for pgfplots, which I found [here](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots_unstable.pdf), there is a snippet of code about using this horizontal line pattern at page 81, and if I click on the `blue` in the snippet, it sends me to a list of colors page 191 of the same document that contains, among others, `violet`.

**What I want to do:** in a first time, use the color violet as a filling for my chart, and ideally I'd like to be able to define a custom color (e.g. `\definecolor{myPurple}{RGB}{73,10,61}`) and use it as a filling for the bar chart.

*edit:*

- I am using Windows 10 pro 64bits with MikTex
- MikTex version is 2.9.6420
- latexmk version `Latexmk, John Collins, 19 Jan. 2017. Version 4.52c`
- lualatex version `This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (MiKTeX 2.9.6420 NEXT 64-bit)`

Comment: Regarding manuals: you likely have them installed as part of MikTeX. Try opening the Start menu, type `texdoc pgf` in the search field and hit enter. If that doesn't work, open a command prompt and type the same thing. That should open the documentation for `pgf`/TikZ, corresponding to the version you have installed. If you do that, and find the description of the `patterns` library, you'll see that there are just a couple of such filled patterns defined by default. They are not directly linked to colours, in the sense that you can just type a different colour name (as you've seen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new pattern similar to `horizontal lines light blue`, where you set the two colours of the pattern yourself.

(`pgfplots` loads `xcolor`, so no need to load `color` separately.)

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\definecolor{myPurple}{RGB}{73,10,61}

% based on code in pgflibrarypatterns.code.tex
% corresponding to horizontal lines light blue, with a different colour
\pgfdeclarepatterninherentlycolored{horizontal lines Purple} % define name of pattern here
{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{100pt}{4pt}}
{\pgfpoint{100pt}{4pt}}
{
  \pgfsetfillcolor{myPurple} % set first colour
  \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{100pt}{2.5pt}}
  \pgfusepath{fill}
  \pgfsetfillcolor{myPurple!90} % set second colour
  \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{2pt}}{\pgfpoint{100pt}{2.5pt}}
  \pgfusepath{fill}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      [
      axis lines*=left,
      xbar,
      xlabel={Pourcentage d'activité},
      symbolic y coords={Énergies},
      ytick=data,
      xmin=0,
      xmax=50,
      nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
      nodes near coords align={horizontal}
      ]
      \addplot[pattern=horizontal lines Purple]
      coordinates{(33,Énergies)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, many thanks for that and the tip about doc ! :)